# Mongo aggregation: add field derived from another field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have documents of the following form present in a collection:

```
{
  name: "Michael",
  likes: [{ name: "reading", amount: 80}, {name: "eating", amount: 70}]
}
```

I want to add a new field to all the documents which will be 0/1 depending on whether the person likes reading. I have to check for the presence of likes.name = "reading".
I tried adding the following stage in my aggregation pipeline to achieve this:

```
$addFields: {
  likes_reading: {
    $cond: {
      if: {
        $eq: ["$likes.name", "reading"]
      },
      then: 1,
      else: 0
    }
  }
}
```

However, $eq doesn't seem to be checking if "any" element of likes array has the required name, which is the kind of behaviour I've seen in many other places when we compare values with arrays. As a result all the likes_reading are set to 0. I need help setting this new field properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `likes` is an array you have to use [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) operator so try this:

```js
{
    $addFields: {
        likes_reading: {
            $cond: {
                if: { $in: ["reading", "$likes.name"] },
                then: 1,
                else: 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or

```js
{
    $addFields: {
        likes_reading: {
            $cond: [{ $in: ["reading", "$likes.name"] }, 1, 0]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had a feeling that $eq wasn't going to work here, but couldn't figure out what to replace it with. I had used $in to match a document's field to an array of values that needed to be searched. This seems to be the reverse of that.
Thank you for the help!